# Why am I allowed to use variable as property name in javascript object creation without using ES6 bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Consider the following example

```js
var x = 1;
var obj = {y:1, x};
console.log(obj, obj.x);
```

I have tried to find many stackoverflow posts and MDN documentations, but I fail to find any reference that says we can use variables as object keys without the ES6 array syntax. That is, I assume js allows `var x=1; var obj2 = {y:1, [x]: 3}`.

Is there some sort of object destructuring happening? Why can I use a variable as property name in the object literal creation without even assigning that property a value?

Comment: `{x}` is shorthand for `{x:x}` - as clearly [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) - it's been around for over 7 years on all browsers :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I have been living under a stone for 7 years :-D never came across this notation.